# Diagnose connection pool leak sourse

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, clr

I have a large web asp.net application which was written mostly by other persons. There seems to be connection pool leak. Please, could you tell me the way to diagnose the sourse of the leak? Most simple / most reliable / quick way to do it?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have a data access class or connection is created in each page?

Comment: It has some kind of self-written dal. I want to find all sources (file and line) of connection loss, where it was opened but not closed or disposed. Any tools or ideas how to do it?

Comment: How do you actually handle connection lifetime in your self-written DAL right now? When and where are you instantiating them? Without details it is hard to tell. If you are instantiating them in 50 different places and then disposing them (or not) at various different places, then you will have to go through it manually.

Comment: Yes, the situation seems to be just like you said: connections are created and disposed in different places. I mean some tool like memory leak detectors in cpp. Maybe CLR profiler could help? Any other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Track connection leaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741813/track-connection-leaks)

Comment: Yes, the answer in this thread explains how to make sure that code does not close connectnios. I want to know how to find all places in code that opens connections which are not closed later.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a common point for the connection (helper class), then you can create connections inside using block.

Ex:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
{  
 //you code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server...

Have you tried using the Activiy Monitor in SQL Server Management Studion?  In the past I have used this to solve the same issue.

1. Open Activity Monitor on the server
2. Open processes
3. Scan the list
4. If connections are not being disposed of correctly, you should see lots of items for your application.
5. Right-click on one and select details.  Note the command SQL in the window.  Repeat for a few.
6. If you see the same command repeated, chances are that's your leak.

Crude but effective; there may be better ways but this worked for me.  Good luck!